# VTK/ITK project Requested modules not available on ubuntu

Tags: c++, linux, qt, vtk, itk

I would like to configure with cmake-gui a VTK/ITK project on ubuntu with QT and I have this error message.

I don't understand. How I can pass this error ?

```
CMake Error at /usr/local/VTK/VTK-7.1.0/CMake/vtkModuleAPI.cmake:120     (message):
  Requested modules not available:

    vtkGUISupportQtOpenGL
Call Stack (most recent call first):
/usr/local/VTK/VTK-7.1.0-build/VTKConfig.cmake:76 (vtk_module_config)
  CMakeLists.txt:24 (FIND_PACKAGE)
```

Comment: There is a way to disable modules using cmake-gui or ccmake however you probably don't want to go without opengl support.

Comment: Hi, how did you fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When configuring VTK with CMake, you need to enable either `vtkGUISupportQtOpenGL` or `VTK_Group_Qt`.

You can also change that setting now, then rebuild and `sudo make install`.

Comment: How should change setting, I didn't understand what should I do.I have something like him `CMake Error at /usr/lib/cmake/vtk-7.1/vtkModuleAPI.cmake:120 (message):
  Requested modules not available:

    vtkGUISupportQtOpenGL
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/lib/cmake/vtk-7.1/VTKConfig.cmake:89 (vtk_module_config)
  CMakeLists.txt:18 (find_package)
`

Comment: Take a look at https://gitlab.kitware.com/vtk/vtk/-/blob/master/Documentation/dev/build.md or older version of instructions at https://vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Configure_and_Build